# sharepoint file download link using rest api

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am doing Salesforce integration with SharePoint using OAuth 'client_credential' method. I am able to fetch file content and but unable to render that content as a word or pdf.or image file. Is there any URL which I can hit and it download file automatically in the browser.

```
HttpRequest reqWrite = new HttpRequest();
        Http httpWrite = new Http();
        endpoint = 'xxx.com/sites/dpmqa/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(\'/sites/xxx/Records/xxx/xxx.docx\')/$value';reqWrite.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        reqWrite.setMethod('GET');
        reqWrite.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');reqWrite.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+ accessToken);HttpResponse resWrite = new HttpResponse();         
        try{ 
            resWrite = httpWrite.send(reqWrite);
```

Comment: Can you post your current code here? How are you making REST call to retrieve the file?

Comment: HttpRequest reqWrite = new HttpRequest();
        Http httpWrite = new Http();
        endpoint = 'xxx.com/sites/dpmqa/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(\'/sites/xxx/Records/xxx/xxx.docx\')/$value';reqWrite.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        reqWrite.setMethod('GET');
        reqWrite.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');reqWrite.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+ accessToken);HttpResponse resWrite = new HttpResponse();         
        try{ 
            resWrite = httpWrite.send(reqWrite);